# Como correr uma notificação ao disparar o alarme?

Tags: android

Ai tenho a minha class `MainActivty` e `ReceberAlarm`, a classe `receberAlarm` é a classe que deve disparar a notificação, peço ajuda.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
static final int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

GPSTracker gps;
public Double latitude;
public Double longitude;
MyAdapter mAdapter;

ViewPager mPager;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_pager);
    setUpPagerAndTabs();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 5);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 22);
    //calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,17); //Indicar horas
    //calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,35);//Indicar Minutos

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReceberAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,0, intent,0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    //Definir o alarme para acontecer no dia determinado                                                                                                     alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pIntent);
}
```

A classe que recebi o alarme:

```
public class ReceberAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      MainActivity m = new MainActivity();
      m.showNotification(); // Activar Notificação
  }
}
```

Comment: Gabriel, você não pode/deveria instânciar uma `Activity`. Por questões de variáveis do contexto e etc... O que você deve fazer é criar uma classe que faça a criação da notificação e usa-lá passando o `Context` como parâmetro em ambos os lugares.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar da seguinte forma:

**No onReceive você dispara o notification.**

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icone)
        .setContentTitle("Título")
        .setContentText("Mensagem");

int mNotificationId = 001;
NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = 
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Nao sei porque mas nao esta reconhecer essa palavra reservada...Criei uma classe pra notificacao que recebe no construtor o contexto e depois lanco o contexto para o  metodo da que cria a notificacao

Comment: Qual palavra reservada?